# Importing Large Dataset in Core Data

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, large-data

I'm trying to import large amout of data according to this [solution.](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/08/22/importing-and-displaying-large-data-sets-in-core-data/) It is suggested that each importing threads should have its own `managedObjectContext` and they cannot pass any `managedObject` among them. So, my question is how we can set the relationship if two objects was created in different MOCs?

PS: After saving MOC in thread, it notifies the main MOC to merge the contexts. So related object for new object is always located in main MOC. In other words related object has already been created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass `NSManagedObject`s between threads, but you can pass `NSManagedObjectID`s.

Pass those over, and then retrieve the objects themselves from the context that you want to set the relationship within.

Comment: Thanks man, after i check Apple's documentation about [Concurrency with Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW1) I found
 `Pass its object ID (objectID) and use objectWithID: or existingObjectWithID:error: on the receiving managed object context.` 

It helped me alot

Comment: Would you know the answer to this (I have the same problem): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500097/importing-saving-and-displaying-large-data-sets-using-background-thread. It's something related to CanP's question. Thanks in advance.