# importing, saving and displaying large data sets using background thread

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, multithreading

I have followed Cocoa is my girl friend's tutorial [here](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/08/22/importing-and-displaying-large-data-sets-in-core-data/), which is based on a subclass of `NSOperation` to fetch and load big number of records in a background thread, but in my case I have several thousands of records which take 1-2 minutes of continuous loading from a remote web service. The app have web service proxy classes generated using [SudzC](http://sudzc.com/). There is no memory leaks detected. The problem occurs after the app finishes loading and saving this huge number of records into sqlite database (using core data), I notice that this import/save operation consumes so much memory, i.e.  after this operation finishes, I use the app features for couple minutes (opening table views, writing text, etc ...), then i will see a crash that happens due to low memory, if I didn't include the import/save operation the app works fine without any low memory crash!

does anybody have a clue for this problem ?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello JAHelia, I have the EXACTLY same problem (except that I don't use SudzC) and I'm stuck here. Kindly update this if ever you got an answer. Thanks

Comment: @acecapades after some deep research, I believe it's a parser problem, have a look at this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project  each xml parser consumes some amount of memory during the parsing process, the one with a lower memory footprint is TBXML parser and it is the fastest one among others and easy to deal with.